# MAMP: How can I force a php version?

Tags: php, mamp

I recently updated my MAMP version to version 4 and I am given two versions of php that I can run. 7.0.13  or 7.1.0

I would like to run version 7.0.13, but whenever I choose that version, MAMP decides for me that I want 7.1.0

How can I "force" MAMP to use 7.0.13?

I am getting an error on an application that was working prior to upgrading: "Mcrypt is required." I am guessing that's because I am running 7.1.0?

This is what I see in my phpinfo file:

```
--with-mcrypt=shared,
```

I use this in my `.bash_profile` file to tell my system to use MAMP's version of php:

```
# Use MAMP version of PHP
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found some suggestions for editing the bash_profile and whatnot, but in the end I just renamed the 7.1.0 folder in MAMP>bin>php and just added a dot in front of it.

Now MAMP defaults to 7.0.13  :)